# Specify concrete cell sizes in UICollectionViewController?

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewflowlayout, uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

I have a storyboard with `UICollectionViewController` with cell prototypes. The cell size is not specified directly and it causes random UI bugs like stretching cell animation. I want to set the size directly but I didn't found how to do that in xcode 10 (and the latest swift). How to solve this issue?

Note: I know about [UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout) existance but I don't know how to apply it to `UICollectionViewController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`:

1. Make your `UICollectionViewController` or `UIViewController` that contains `UICollectionView` instance to adopt `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

   ```
   class MyAwesomeCollectionViewControler: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
   ```

   { 
   ... 
   }
2. Implement the method below:

   ```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100) // Return desired size here}
   ```

Comment: Sorry but in my case I have code which uses "custom" layout. So how to deal with it? Or maybe don't you know how to jump from "custom" to "flow"?

Comment: @Vyachaslav Gerchicov, in case of custom layout you must override the `func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?`. `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` object has `frame` property. This is where you determine the size. For further reading please see [uicollectionviewlayoutattributes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayoutattributes) and [uicollectionviewlayou](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that there are 2 kinds of layout available - "flow" and "custom" (these names are displayed in interface builder).

In short if you plan to use `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and its simple method "size for item" then you should choose "flow"